# Convert Future<List> from Firestore to List<String> - Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I need to use my list from Firestore, but I'am stuck how to convert my Future list which I get from Firestore to list of strings:

```
Future<List> getListOfProducts() async {
    List<String> productsList;
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
        (await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').get()).docs;
    productsList = documents
        .map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['productName'] as String)
        .toList();
    return productsList;
  }
```

What should I do with productList now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this function is async, it must return a `Future`. However what you can do is `await` the result when calling the function.
`List<String> lst = await getListOfProducts()`

Comment: I tried to do this, but I got "The await expression can only be used in an async function." error.

Comment: That means that you are using the await keyword illegally in a place you cant. How/where are you using it?

Comment: here is my code: 
  List<String> myProductsList = await getListOfProducts();

Comment: I meant where are you using that? Are you using it inside a function that's passed to the `onPressed` of a button? Are you using it in a constructor? etc.

Comment: all is clear now, I forgot about async in my main function, thank You